# Small tools/scripts that help you so much?

Tags: scripting

On top of my head, especially for C/Linux developer:

- [ack](http://petdance.com/ack/)
- [git-bz](http://git.fishsoup.net/cgit/git-bz/plain/git-bz)
- [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html)
- [colordiff](http://colordiff.sourceforge.net/)
- [moap](https://thomas.apestaart.org/moap/trac) and [prepare-ChangeLog](http://svn.gnome.org/svn/releng/trunk/tools/prepare-ChangeLog.pl)

Is there some tool/script you couldn't work without, but that you feel others don't know so much?

For instance, I just found:

- [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.wiki.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: If you're going to vote it down, at least add a comment about why.

Comment: thanks UnhipGlint, I keep rephrasing to make it look more like a question :)

Comment: ack was a new one for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use it that often, but the **tool with the highest ratio of awesomeness to being little known** has to be [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf), which is the tool for drawing directed graphs that is part of the [AT&T Graph Visualization](http://www.graphviz.org) suite.  A nice example output is their [Unix family tree](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/unix.html).

Answer (score 4):

On Windows or Linux:

1. grep, without a doubt
2. tail
3. vim

On Windows (and Linux, Solaris), [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net)

I realize that grep and tail are well-known, but it amazes me how many people think it's magic when you use either one of them. Same thing with Vim. I'm hardly a power user, but I can open it up and have a *small* document complete before MS Word would even open.

Comment: `tail -f -n 0 log.file`, do your dirty deed and check what went wrong. Wow.

Comment: Get in the habit of tail -F instead of tail -f, -F follows log files even after rotation.

Answer (score 3):

[Vim http://www.straw-dogs.co.uk/wp-content/vim_logo.png](http://www.straw-dogs.co.uk/wp-content/vim_logo.png)

[Vim, my favorite editor](http://www.vim.org/)

Comment: That's only small in comparison to EMACS, so that doesn't really count!

Comment: Yeah, only small, elegant and useful utilities, Emacs is a nice operating system, but lacks a good editor... LOL

Answer (score 2):

- StackOverflow
- Google

And my other two favourites are too large to be considered small :P

- Visual Studio
- The Internet

Comment: Since the question was edited, my answer isn't as relevant any more as everyone knows about them...it's a little unfair for penalising me for an edited question.  But c'est la vie I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

It's a language not a tool, but it is **small** and not yet well known: the programming language [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).  I **can't live without it** and it is gradually displacing my sh, ksh, awk, and perl scripts...  One mark of genius: the escape character for string-search patterns is *different* from the escape character for quoted strings.  No more trying to make sense of legions of backslashes!

Answer (score 2):

- git has had such a profound impact on my workflow that I do not want to code without it
- firebug is a must for web development
- standard command-line utilities/functions: grep, find, locate, tail, sed, awk, pushd, popd
- custom TextMate bundle snippets, TextMate's bundle editor is superb even though TextMate lacks some important vi and emacs capabilities (like split buffers)
- regular expressions - people need to learn how-to use regexps, period

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite fond of:

1. [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)
2. [Sysinternals (a bunch of cool tools here)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The python interactive interpreter and its pumped up variant [iPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) are the tools that have enhanced my programming productivity like no other.

Being able to experiment with new code on the fly and inspect objects, classes, and modules in any way you want interactively is simply awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Does know one depend on Putty ?, i really dunno what i would do with out it

Answer (score 1):

Most have been listed here already so I won't repeat.  Here are a couple new ones.

[LINQ Pad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

[Sticky Notes VS Add-In](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/StickyNotes)

psValidation (My own Validation Class Library, Mostly RegEx)

Answer (score 0):

```
- ANT
- Mylyn
- TortoiseSVN
- firebug (think console too!)
- TextMate
```

Answer (score 0):

My faves are [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm), which I use for EVERYTHING that's not wrapped in a visual studio project, and a small macro in Visual studio that turns a c# variable declaration into a basic property. Both are simple, but oh so very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I need the most tools when coding for web, anything else usually just a text editor.

for web:

- [Web Developer Add-On for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)
- [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/)
- [Pixie](http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.html)
- [MeasureIt Add-On for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/539)

Answer (score 0):

Vim and [PrintFile](http://www.lerup.com/printfile). All PrintFile does is print text and PostScript files, any which way I want them (including cut-and-paste).

Answer (score 0):

Already listed but I must mention [TextMate](http://macromates.com/).  I use [Mercurial or Hg](http://selenic.com/wiki/Mercurial) on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug. More than anything else.